# Llenar tabla con los datos de un archivo serializado

Tags: java, serialización

Tengo este código que me serializa una clase Contacto:

```
@Override
public void serializar() {
       Contacto a= new Contacto();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("contactos.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        if(oos != null)
        {
            oos.writeObject(a);
            oos.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contacto guardado");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hubo un error en el proceso\n"
                + "Ha ocurrido el siguiente error: \n"+e);
    }
}
```

y éste que me deserializa el archivo:

```
  public void deserializar() {
    Contacto a;

    try {
        File file=new File("contactos.dat");

        if(file.exists()) {

        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream ios= new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        if(ios != null){
            a= (Contacto) ios.readObject();
            ios.close();
        }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hubo un error en el proceso\n"
                + "Ha ocurrido el siguiente error: \n"+e);
    }
}
```

Están en diferentes clases de ahí que haga referencia a la clase contacto en cada una de ellas

Lo que quiero saber es como puedo llenar una tabla con los datos que genera la clase serializadora en el archivo

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario crear un serializador/deserializador para cada clase. Puedes aprovechar **generics** para usar uno solo.

```
public class Serializator {

    public static <T> void serialize(String path, T t) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {

             oos.writeObject(t);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> Optional<T> deserialize(String path, Class<T> type) {
        try (FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(path);
             ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(fos)) {

             return Optional.of((T) ios.readObject());
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // hacer algo en lugar de esto
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

El modo uso es simple:

```
Serializator.serialize("/ruta/archivo.dat", objeto);
Optional<Objeto> optObjecto = Serializator.deserialize("/ruta/archivo.dat", Objeto.class);
if(optObjecto.isPresent()) { // si el objeto está presente
    Objeto objeto = optObjeto.get();
    // proceder a insertar
}
```

Ahora, no entiendo a qué te refieres con tabla. ¿Base de datos? ¿JTable/TableView?

#### Base de datos

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO tu_tabla(col1, col2, col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

    try (Connection conn = ConnectionHelper.get();
         PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        pst.setString(1, person.getName());
        pst.setString(2, person.getLastname());
        pst.setDate(3, person.getBirthDate());
        pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        // hacer algo si falla el insert
    }
```

Donde:

- **ConnectionHelper** es una clase utilitaria para obtener la conexión

**Modo JPA**

No hay mayor misterio, obtienes el `EntityManager` y guardas el objeto.

```
entityManager.save(person);
```

#### JTable

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tabla.getModel();
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

model.addRow(new Object[] {
    person.getName(), person.getLastname(), fmt.format(person.getBirthDate())
});
```

Comment: Es JTable, gracias

Comment: De nada amigo. Saludos.

Comment: Puedes mejorar la definición del genérico para que solo admita `Serializable`s y así evitar problemas de serialización de clases que no implementan dicha interfaz como `java.util.Scanner` (sí, puede pasar, lo he visto).